# Cursor и Listener

Tags: android, listview, observer

Добрый день.

Как реализовать обновление ListView, при изменение переменной типа Cursor.

К примеру ListView находится в MainActivity ,  а Cursor в синглтоне DataSource, который реализует методы работы с SQLite, возвращая значение курсора в свою переменную allRows. (то есть при действии достает все значения из бд и пихает в данную переменную).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать для этого **BroadcastReceiver**

создать его в адаптере:

```
final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(android.content.Context context, android.content.Intent intent)
    {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(NOTIFICATION_DATA_CHANGED))
        {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
};
```

не забыть зарегистрировать/сбросить:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    registerReceiver(mAdapter.getReceiver(), new IntentFilter(NOTIFICATION_DATA_CHANGED));
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mAdapter.getReceiver());
}
```

при изменении данных курсора посылать широковещательное сообщение:

```
mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(NOTIFICATION_DATA_CHANGED));
```

Comment: @Роман Захаров, спасибо за ответ. Но у меня сразу есть несколько вопросов, так как впервые работаю с листенарами. 

Адаптером, получается, у меня является DataSource, в котором методы для работы с БД? Или это MainActivity, где у меня листвью?

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, адаптер - это адаптер листвью. если ты создаешь свой адаптер наследованием от BaseAdapter, то BroadcastReceiver нужно определить там. Если ты используешь CursorAdapter, тогда BroadcastReceiver нужно определить в Activity где у тебя находится листвью